# Starting delayed Intent while calling phone number

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the following code to start a phone call to number 123456, what I'm having problems with is starting another call with a new number and a delay of maybe 2-3 seconds while the first call is still calling.

I have tried Thread.sleep(), Handler, startActivityForResult() and so on but they all wait for me to push the back button so I'm back in my app before it starts the second call.

```
String num = "tel:123456";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
intent.setData(Uri.parse(num));  
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit:

I added the following before starting the second call and it seams like it's working like it should.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

When your activity is put to background it's main thread is no longer active, so what you are trying to do does not work.

Try starting a background thread, and executing your code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler:

```
Handler delayedCallHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    String num = (String) msg.obj;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(num));
    startActivity(intent);`
  }
};
```

And in your code, you can launch the activity with delay:

```
delayedCallHandler.sendMessage(
    delayedCallHandler.obtainMessage(0, "tel:123456"), // msg.obj = the number to call
    2000); // 2 seconds
```